# Storybook freezing after showing animation

Tags: react-native, storybook

I am facing some trouble with showing a toast animation in Storybook. The toast animation loads in the storybook and works properly but after the animation is  finished, storybook freezes without any showing any error or message.

> Toast.stories.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { ComponentMeta, ComponentStory } from "@storybook/react";

import { ComponentWrapper } from "../../setup/Wrappers";
import Toast from "./Toast";

export default {
  title: "components/Toast",
  component: Toast,
  args: {
    message: "Error Toast",
    type: "error",
    onClose: () => {
      console.log("Closing");
    },
  },
} as ComponentMeta<typeof Toast>;

export const BasicToast: ComponentStory<typeof Toast> = args => (
  <ComponentWrapper>
    <Toast {...args} />
  </ComponentWrapper>
);

BasicToast.args = {};
```

> Toast.tsx:

The logs of onClose and closeToast work properly but after the toast finishes, storybook sidebar links don't work, can it be because of the transform output range dimensions?

```
const { UIManager } = NativeModules;

UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental &&
  UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);

const animationConfig = { toValue: 1, duration: 300, useNativeDriver: true };

const Toast: React.FC<ToastProps> = ({ message, type, onClose }) => {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = React.useState(false);
  const fadeAnimation = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0.5)).current;
  const { colors } = useTheme();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (isVisible) Animated.timing(fadeAnimation, animationConfig).start();

    setTimeout(closeToast, 3000);
  }, [isVisible]);

  function closeToast() {
    Animated.timing(fadeAnimation, { ...animationConfig, toValue: 0 }).start(() => {
      console.log("Animation Closed");
      setIsVisible(false);
      onClose?.();
    });
  }

  return (
    <Modal transparent visible>
      <Animated.View
        style={[
          styles.container,
          {
            transform: [
              {
                translateX: fadeAnimation.interpolate({
                  inputRange: [0, 1],
                  outputRange: [Dimensions.get("window").width, 0],
                }),
              },
            ],
            opacity: fadeAnimation,
            backgroundColor: colors[type || "link"],
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Pressable onPress={closeToast}>
          <AppText style={styles.message}>{message}</AppText>
        </Pressable>
      </Animated.View>
    </Modal>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    position: "absolute",
    borderRadius: 12,
    top: 40,
    width: "20%",
    left: "40%",
    right: "10%",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    padding: 10,
    flex: 1,
  },
  message: { color: "white" },
});


export default Toast;
```